# Relocating to the UK

Tags: united-kingdom

We are planning to relocate to England in June and are trying to buy a house there before we arrive. We have a daughter there who is going to see the house for us.
Can we have our furniture delivered to the address while we are in quarantine?
Are we able to rent a car from the airport when we arrive?

Comment: Where are you relocating *from*?

Comment: You could do with splitting up your questions - one actual question per post please.
Also note that COVID related rules are liable to have changed by June. (And on a personal note I'd strongly dissuade you from buying a house you haven't seen, but that is your choice)

Comment: The simple part of the question, which is on topic here, is that yes, you can rent a car at the airport.

Comment: What's your concern about airport car rentals? It's easy to contact rental companies or check their websites and most seem to be still open. Is there some reason you think you would not be able to rent? If there's a particular location/company you're worried about (because some branches might close or have limited hours), you should either specify it here, or contact them.